# Get summary of the model using purrr::map within dplyr piping

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Using `mtcars` data, I am testing `map()` to build some `lm()` models:

```r
library(tidyverse)

 mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()%>%
  mutate(fit = map(.x=data,~lm(mpg ~ ., data = .x)))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>     cyl data               fit     
#>   <dbl> <list>             <list>  
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 x 10]>  <S3: lm>
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]> <S3: lm>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]> <S3: lm>
```

The output shows that I have a new column, `fit`.

**Now I wish to see the `summary` of each `lm`**

When I try:

```r
library(tidyverse)

 mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()%>%
  mutate(fit = map(.x=data,~lm(mpg ~ ., data = .x))) %>%
  map(fit,summary)

#> Error in as_mapper(.f, ...): object 'fit' not found
```

It gives the error:

> `Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : object 'fit' not found`

If I wish to calculate `R2` or `aic` then I can using the following code without any problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(modelr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()%>%
  mutate(fit = map(.x=data,~lm(mpg ~ ., data = .x))) %>%
   mutate(r2 = map_dbl(fit, ~rsquare(., data = mtcars)),
         aic = map_dbl(fit, ~AIC(.))) %>% 
  arrange(aic)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>     cyl data               fit           r2    aic
#>   <dbl> <list>             <list>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 x 10]>  <S3: lm>  -8.96  -Inf  
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]> <S3: lm> -26.4     56.4
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]> <S3: lm>  -1.000   67.3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What am I missing?

Comment: The object `fit` does not exist in the global environment. While many `dplyr` functions like `mutate` look for objects inside your data.frame, `map` does not do this. If you want to see the summaries you can replace `map(fit,summary)` with `%>% pull(fit) %>% map(summary)`. If you want the summaries as a column you can use `%>% mutate(fit_summ = map(fit, summary))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [IceCreamToucan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56634033/get-summary-from-model-using-map-purrr-in-r#comment99840107_56634033) laid out, `purrr::map` does not look into the data which has been made within your piping.

If you use it with `dplyr::mutate` then it has access to `fit` which you have created in the previous piping.

Another option would be explicitly referring to `fit` which you can see below, as my second suggestion.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()%>%
  mutate(fit = map(.x=data,~lm(mpg ~ ., data = .x))) %>% 
  mutate(fit_sum = map(fit,summary)) 
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>     cyl data               fit    fit_sum   
#>   <dbl> <list>             <list> <list>    
#> 1     6 <tibble [7 x 10]>  <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>
#> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]> <lm>   <smmry.lm>

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()%>%
  mutate(fit = map(.x=data,~lm(mpg ~ ., data = .x))) %>%
  {map(.$fit, summary)} #or using pull: `pull(fit) %>% map(summary)`

#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = .x)
#> 
#> Residuals:
#> ALL 7 residuals are 0: no residual degrees of freedom!
#> 
#> Coefficients: (3 not defined because of singularities)
#>             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
#> (Intercept) 32.78649         NA      NA       NA
#> disp         0.07456         NA      NA       NA
#> hp          -0.04252         NA      NA       NA
#> drat         1.52367         NA      NA       NA
#> wt           5.12418         NA      NA       NA
#> qsec        -2.33333         NA      NA       NA
#> vs          -1.75289         NA      NA       NA
#> am                NA         NA      NA       NA
#> gear              NA         NA      NA       NA
#> carb              NA         NA      NA       NA
#> 
#> Residual standard error: NaN on 0 degrees of freedom
#> Multiple R-squared:      1,  Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
#> F-statistic:   NaN on 6 and 0 DF,  p-value: NA

####truncated the results for the sake of space####
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

From the latest release of `dplyr`, `tidyverse` seems to be encouraging using `group_modify` functions instead of using `purrr` + nested dataframes.

In that workflow, here is how you can get both model summaries and estimates in the same dataframe via `broom` package:

```r
# setup
set.seed(123)
library(tidyverse)
options(tibble.width = Inf)

# joining dataframes with regression estimates and model summaries
dplyr::full_join(
 # to get a tidy dataframe of regression estimates
  x = mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    group_modify(.f = ~ broom::tidy(lm(mpg ~ ., data = .x), conf.int = TRUE)),
  # to get a tidy dataframe of model summaries
  y = mtcars %>%
    group_by(cyl) %>%
    group_modify(.f = ~ broom::glance(lm(mpg ~ ., data = .x))),
  by = "cyl"
) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup(x = .)

#> Warning in qt(a, object$df.residual): NaNs produced

#> # A tibble: 25 x 20
#>      cyl term        estimate std.error statistic.x p.value.x conf.low
#>    <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     4 (Intercept)  60.9      180.         0.338      0.793 -2229.  
#>  2     4 disp         -0.345      0.469     -0.735      0.596    -6.31
#>  3     4 hp           -0.0332     0.364     -0.0915     0.942    -4.65
#>  4     4 drat         -4.19      46.4       -0.0903     0.943  -594.  
#>  5     4 wt            4.48      29.7        0.151      0.905  -373.  
#>  6     4 qsec         -0.106      7.82      -0.0136     0.991   -99.4 
#>  7     4 vs           -3.64      34.0       -0.107      0.932  -435.  
#>  8     4 am           -6.33      45.2       -0.140      0.912  -581.  
#>  9     4 gear          4.07      29.1        0.140      0.912  -366.  
#> 10     4 carb          3.22      28.2        0.114      0.928  -355.  
#>    conf.high r.squared adj.r.squared sigma statistic.y p.value.y    df
#>        <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1   2351.       0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#>  2      5.62     0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#>  3      4.59     0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#>  4    586.       0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#>  5    382.       0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#>  6     99.2      0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#>  7    428.       0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#>  8    568.       0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#>  9    374.       0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#> 10    362.       0.928         0.276  3.84        1.42     0.576     9
#>    logLik   AIC   BIC deviance df.residual  nobs
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <int> <int>
#>  1  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#>  2  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#>  3  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#>  4  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#>  5  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#>  6  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#>  7  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#>  8  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#>  9  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#> 10  -17.2  56.4  60.8     14.7           1    11
#> # ... with 15 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>